PyQt QLineSeries QChart Как спрятать кусок графика
График, два окошка куда вбиваем края диапазона, который хотим спрятать. Потом нажимаем кнопку.
Как это сделать? Методы clear, hide, update не подходят.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QLabel
from PySide6.QtCharts import QLineSeries, QChart, QChartView, QValueAxis
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt, QPen, QIntValidator, QBrush
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt,  QCoreApplication
import sys


class ChartWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(700, 500)
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        self.x_start = 0
        self.x_stop = 500
        self.y_axis = QValueAxis()
        self.y_axis.setRange(0, 20)
        self.y_axis.setLabelFormat("%0.2f")
        self.y_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        self.y_axis.setTickInterval(5)
        axisBrush = QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.black)
        self.y_axis.setTitleBrush(axisBrush)
        self.x_axis = QValueAxis()
        self.x_axis.setRange(self.x_start, self.x_stop)
        self.x_axis.setLabelFormat("%d")
        self.x_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        self.x_axis.setTickInterval(100)
        self.chart.addAxis(self.x_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        self.chart.addAxis(self.y_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.series = QLineSeries()
        for i in range(0, 500, 1):
            self.series.append(i, 10)
        self.series.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red, 2))
        self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.x_axis)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.y_axis)
        right_column = self.right_column()
        chart_view = QChartView(self.chart)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(chart_view, 8)
        hbox.addWidget(right_column, 2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

def right_column(self):
        self.right_column_widget = QWidget()
        self.right_column_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.right_column_widget.setLayout(self.right_column_layout)
        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit1.setPlaceholderText("Значение 1")
        self.lineEdit1.setValidator(QIntValidator(-999, 999, self))
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2.setPlaceholderText("Значение 2")
        self.lineEdit2.setValidator(QIntValidator(-999, 999, self))
        self.btn = QPushButton("go!")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.__handleChart)
        self.right_column_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.right_column_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        self.right_column_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)
        self.right_column_layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.right_column_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.right_column_layout.addStretch(1)
        return self.right_column_widget

def __handleChart(self):
        for i in range(int(self.lineEdit1.text()), int(self.lineEdit2.text()), 1):
            # ?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cw = ChartWindow()
    cw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

